# Kivy FloatLayout in multiple screens

Tags: python, kivy

The FLoatLayout in kivy seems to restricted to only one screen per time. I want to use multiple screens and apply FloatLayout on all of them.

### **What I have tried:**

1. I know I can separate all the screens into different kivy and python
   files then combine them, but I don't want to because of ease of use.
2. I tried allowing my classes (Screens) to inherit from both screen
   and FloatLayout, but apparently the ScreenManager does not accept
   'non-screen inputs'
3. I am using kivy Language, (not python) so I can not just assign
   widgets to the FloatLayout inside a window class then return it.

ps. The reason I want to use FloatLayout is to avoid overlapping widgets. I wouldn't mind using another layout if it produces a similar result.

Comment: The option of overlapping widgets is what you get with FloatLayout... (also with RelativeLayout). BoxLayout and GridLayout are some of the layouts that prevent overlapping. And is there a reson for not just using `screen1.add_widget(MyFloatLayoutWidget)` for your screens?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was a little confused. The reason I didn't want to use screen1.add_widget was I was afraid that doing so would affect the kivy language code. I would try out the BoxLayout and then send my results!

Comment: You can also put it in the kv part. I'll write you an answer to show you the code...

Answer (score 0):

You can add another layout in your screen like this (in the kv part of the code):

```
    ScreenManager:
        id: screens
        Screen:
            name: "main"
            id: main
            BoxLayout:
                id: main_box
```

You can do something similar in the python part of the code by using:

```
main_box = BoxLayout()
self.ids.main.add_widget(main_box)
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple screens, you need to declarete then as a screenmanager at kv file, in this case the screenmanager name is CustomScreen, you need the screens and the Float Layout:

```
<CustomScreen>:
    screen1:
    screen2:
    screen3:

<screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:'open FloatLayout'
            on_press:root.openFloatExample()
        Button:
            text: 'close FloatLayout'
            on_press:root.closeFloatExample()

<screen2>:
    BoxLayout:

<floatExample>:
    FloatLayout:
       BoxLayout:
```

In your Python code you declare the CustomScreen, and add the screens as widgets, then you need to create an object that will recive the FloatLayout at the inicialization of the screen, and than you can utilize this objetct, add or remove it from the screen:

```
class CustomScreen(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CustomScreen, self).__init__()
        self.add_widget(tela1())
        self.add_widget(tela2())

class tela1(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(tela1, self).__init__()

        global objetoFloatLayout
        objetoFloatLayout = floatExample()
    
    def openFloatExample(self):
        self.add_widget(objetoFloatLayout)
    
    def closeFloatExample(self):
        self.remove_widget(objetoFloatLayout)

class tela2(Screen):
    def __init__(self):
        super(tela2, self).__init__()


class floatExample(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(floatExample,self).__init__()
```